# runtime to find middle element using AVL tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, runtime, avl-tree

I have an one lecture slides says following:
To find middle element in AVL tree, I traverse elements in order until It reaches the moddile element. It takes O(N).

If I know correctly, in tree structure, finding element takes base 2 O(logn) since AVL is binary tree that always divided into 2 childs.

But why it says O(N)?

Comment: Yes, if you know the value of the middle element it would take O(log n), but since middle element is not known before hand, you have to count (n/2 -
 1) smallest elements in the tree and the next element would be the middle element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just trying to elaborate 'A. Mashreghi' comment.

Since, the tree under consideration is AVL tree - the guaranteed finding of element in O(log n) holds as log as you have the element(key) to find.

The problem is - you are trying to identify a middle element in the given data structure. As it is AVL tree (self balanced BST) in-order travel gives you elements in ascending order. You want to use this property to find the middle element.

Algorithm goes like - have a counter increment for every node traversed in-order and return @ n/2th position. This sums to O(n/2) and hence the overall complexity O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Being divided into 2 children does not guarantee perfect symmetry.  For instance, consider the most unbalanced of all balanced binary trees: each right child has a depth one more than its corresponding left child.
In such a tree, the middle element will be somewhere down in the right branch's left branch's ...

You need to determine how many nodes `N` you have, then locate the `N/2`th largest node.  This is not **O(log N)** process.

Comment: Since the tree under consideration is AVL tree, cant we assume that skewed tree structures are not the case for O(n). May the explanation about number(key) value not known - is the factor. You have count n/2 numbers (in order traversal) to be sure about the middle element.